# Rails 4: can't add new method to ActiveRecord from app/lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, module, include

I try create app on Rails 4 and I create lib file

app/lib/userstamp

```
module Userstamp

  module MigrationHelper
    def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      def userstamps(include_deleter_id = false)
        column(:creator_id, :integer)
        column(:updater_id, :integer)
        column(:deleter_id, :integer) if include_deleter_id
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition.send(:include, Userstamp::MigrationHelper)
```

...and add autoload to app/config/application.rb

```
module App
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...

    # Autoload lib/ folder including all subdirectories
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
  end
end
```

...and create new migration in my app/db/migrate

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.userstamps
    end
  end
end
```

Why I get this error?

```
undefined method `userstamps' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007feca6a11608>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include Userstamp::MigrationHelper 

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.userstamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.